# Version 1.2.2 no longer renders MathJax in comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app, mathjax

In earlier versions of the iOS app, clicking on Render MathJax worked just fine, but it no longer does in 1.2.2. What happened?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  Is there a specific comment you're looking at?

Comment: @BrianNickel: It happens to me on every comment. There's no response to my pressing  "Render MathJax." I have started having all sorts of problems since I installed iOS8.1 on the iPad, so perhaps it's OS-related. (Currently running iOS8.1.3.)